# create a shortcode for embedding google map in a page

Tags: shortcode, google-maps

I'm trying to create a shortcode that lets you embed google map anywhere in wordpress page.

shortcode must be able to pass two attributes ( latitude and longitude )

Below is edited question ( I did not edit whole question as there exists answer for above question )

Adding shortcode wasn't suitable choice in my case as there were be multiple locations ( markers on map ).

So, I need to create a map that would load multiple locations.

This is not only problem, there are three places ( eg, place1, place2, place3 ) and each location contains sub locations. The map should load place1 locations when page loads, when clicked on other place tab ( say place2 ) the map should hide place1 locations and load the locations of place2, and same for place3. And finally there exists a tab to load all the places and theri respective locations.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
        function init() {
            // Basic options for a simple Google Map
            // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
            var mapOptions = {
                // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
                zoom: 6,

                // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(62.1630198, 12.9895886), // New York

                // How you would like to style the map. 
                // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
                styles: [{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"all","stylers":
                [{"saturation":"-100"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.province",
                "elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape",
                "elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":65},
                {"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":
                [{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":"50"},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},
                {"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":"-100"}]},
                {"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":
                "simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"all","stylers":
                [{"lightness":"30"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"all","stylers":
                [{"lightness":"40"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":
                [{"saturation":-100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"water",
                "elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#ffff00"},{"lightness":-25},
                {"saturation":-97}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels","stylers":
                [{"lightness":-25},{"saturation":-100}]}]
            };

            // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
            // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
            var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

            // Create the Google Map using our element and options defined above
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

            // Let's also add a marker while we're at it
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400),
                map: map,
                title: 'Location One'
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.6700, -73.9400),
                map: map,
                title: 'Location Two'
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(46.6700, -73.9400),
                map: map,
                title: 'Location Three'
            });
        }
```

I'm using ACF to make fields for longitude and latitude values for locations.

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried so far, what issue are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

```
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'latitude' => '28.66', // default value
    'longitude' => '99.25' // default value
), $atts, 'bartag' );

return <div class="" latitude=" '.$atts['latitude'].' " longitude=" '.$atts['longitude'].' "></div>'; 
} 

add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

Now you can use shortcode like :

```
[bartag latitude='12.34' latitude='12.34']
```

will return :

```
<div class="" latitude="12.34" longitude="12.34"></div>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode#Examples

Comment: appreciate your help